# Wifi no icon and can't add wifi in system preferences

Tags: wifi

I have reinstalled macos high sierra here are some screen shots. [image: No wi-fi icon]

[image: No wi-fi sowing up.]

I have a 17" early  2011 mbp

Comment: Try Apple menu -> About this Mac -> System Report. Under Network entry, do you see Wi-Fi listed? If so, does it list hardware? Entirely possible your hardware has gone faulty, if it isn't listed in System Report then the machine is not able to detect it.

Comment: when I click on network I wifi does not shot up but under network when i see wifi airport util still does not show wifi either

Comment: Does it show **Wi-Fi** in **System Information** under **Network**?  The fact that your **Mac** is ~ 10 years old it could very well be a hardware failure in that the **Airport** card has gone bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely a hardware issue then. I’d recommend taking the system in to a repair shop if you want to try and salvage it.

Comment: Thanks i got a new wifi card and now it works thanks!